# Filter Listview Not Showing Up Properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, filter

I made a filtered listview, however it shows two search boxes:

[image]

My Code:

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="searchevents">
<div data-role="header">
<h1>Search</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <ul id='searchlist' data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search by club or event name..."></ul>
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#searchevents", function() {

    $( "#searchlist" ).on( "listviewbeforefilter", function ( e, data ) {
    var $ul = $( this ),
    $input = $( data.input ),
    value = $input.val(),
    html = "";
    $ul.html( "" );
    if ( value && value.length > 2 ) {
        $ul.html( "<li><div class='ui-loader'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading'></span></div></li>" );
        $ul.listview( "refresh" );
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            crossDomain: true,
            data: {
                q: $input.val()
            }
        })
        .then( function ( response ) {
            $.each( response, function ( i, val ) {
                html += "<li>" + val + "</li>";
            });
            $ul.html( html );
            $ul.listview( "refresh" );
            $ul.trigger( "updatelayout");
        });
    }
    });
});
```

If I take out the

from the HTML code (above), both search boxes go away, so I know it is coming from the same one line source. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `alert('')`'s to various parts of your code, for example, within the `$.each` section, to determine where the duplication is happening. You can expect the alert to be triggered twice in the problematic area, possibly back-to-back, or once during two separate iterations. Then, once you figure out what section is causing the duplication, you can determine which event is responsible and modify your code accordingly.